# Trigger client side event when session in lost

Tags: javascript, session, asp-classic

As some of you probably know, Facebook is using this kind of "system" where a popup is displayed when a user session is lost due to inactivity or distant session close. I already saw and read this [Node.js question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882285/node-js-listen-to-session-variable-change-and-trigger-server-side-event) but didn't find anything.

I am working for a Canadian computer business our main product is a CRM and everything is coded using Classic ASP.

*I know.*

The whole web-based application is working great and since we host the site on our servers, it is possible if necessary to open ports and use sockets.

Here goes the main question: is there a way (using a javascript library or a jQuery plug-in maybe?) to **trigger a client-side event when the session expires** or is simply lost due to a server reset for example?

Of course, the best would be to use another solution than sending an AJAX request every second to validate if the user session still exists. If it can help, there is a maximum of about 3'500 users connected at the same time and our servers can easily handle more traffic. The servers are working on Windows Server 2008 along with IIS 7.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code blocks or screenshots for this question since there is nothing to debug.

One idea would be to use an AJAX request to a file that does not return anything and hangs there. If session is lost (inactivity or server reset), the AJAX request will trigger an error and the "error" function will be triggered. Would that be something to consider?

Or else, any other suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be when page is inactive and nothing is going on? You can check for session timeout when user attempts do do something (click a button, navigate somewhere etc.)

Comment: Also keep in mind, that checking via AJAX every second would refresh the session and effectively PREVENT the session from timeout-ing.

Comment: @gpinkas Indeed, I need something like an AJAX request done on page load that never returns anything and on error (due to server reset or session timeout) prompts user. Would that be a solution?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It has to be "real-time", the user has to be notified the moment the session is lost.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to set client-side timer set to the same time as session expiration time.

Let's say your session is set to expire after 20 minutes. When page loads - client-side timer set to 20 minutes kicks in. If user does any server interaction (submits form etc.) - timer is reset. But if nothing happens during this 20 minutes - timer counts down and you get your event.

Comment: That would be a good solution. The thing is sessions can be ended from elsewhere. For example, if IIS is reset, all sessions are lost but in this case, the user wouldn't be notified.

Comment: @ÉrikRykDesjardins - I deeply suspect you'll have to take this as the best you can get without getting insanely over-complicated. You're not going to be able to cover *every* possible way a session could be lost with the client window open. The better question may be why do you need this?

Comment: @ÉrikRykDesjardins. For those scenarios you will have to do server interaction. E.g. user clicks form submit, server-side code realizes session gone kaput and acts accordinly

Comment: @AnonJr Users have to fill enormous forms that can't be saved until completed (my boss won't consider any other options). There are a lot of ajax requests that require authentication. If the server is reset, the ASP scripts cannot be accessed because the user is not authenticated. The page needs to notify the user when session is lost so that he or she can reenter credentials in order to continue to use the page.

Comment: @ÉrikRykDesjardins well when your mentioned asp script already knows when a user is not authenticated just Show a Login popup or something like this and then log the user in by Ajax... you do not have to notify the clientside that that the session is lost.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following to achieve this, assuming you have a default session timeout of 20:00 minutes:

1. Ensure, that each user has a "session cookie" issued by you, NOT the default ASP Session Cookie.

   ```
   dim live_session_id
   live_session_id = Request.Cookies("livesession")
   if live_session_id = "" then
       live_session_id = create_unique_session_id()
       Response.Cookies("livesession") = live_session_id
   end if
   ```
2. Save this live_session_id in a database along with the expected session expire date

   ```
   call updateSession(live_session_id, dateadd("n", 20, now())) ' = now()+20min
   ```
3. Output the live_session_id somewhere on your page, so you can access it via JS.
4. Implement a serverside ASP script that checks the current session state for a given live_session_id and make it accessible in IIS in a DIFFERENT subdomain, so calls to this check will NOT refresh the ASP session. The script could return the time difference between now and session end, so you could output the duration the session will remain valid.
5. Add some AJAX code to call the check script every other second, so you could issue a warning if the session time draws to an end.
6. To make it detect IIS reset, you could clear the saved sessions in the database by implementing `Application_OnStart` in `global.asa`. This way, your clients would detect a session loss by IIS reset.

### another quick and dirty method

On every page load, you could let a javascript count down from 20:00 minutes and display a session lost warning after this time. This is what my online banking system uses... :)

Comment: That sure is a complete answer. Thank you, I'll be trying the whole thing today. It actually makes a lot of sense; let's hope it'll please everyone here--!

Comment: Great, please let me know if it worked out for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand you the main Problem is that the user has to fill out enormous forms. that could take some time and during that time the session could expire.

furthermore the session could be ended by anything else (iisreset or so) during the time the user fills out the form.

in my understanding you do not have to notify the Client that the session is lost/expired/ended/abandoned. it would be enough to just show a Login form (Ajax or something) when the user submits the form OR the next request (by Ajax as you mentioned) is made by the Client.

the called asp script checks if the session is valid and if not a popup or overlay is shown to Login the user by Ajax first and the form is submitted afterwards.

you could think of a http Status code 401 or something to send back to the Client and the Client then Shows the mentioned Ajax Login form...

Comment: This could be a good solution. Again, because AJAX requests are done WHILE the user is filling the form to dynamically modify the content of some select boxes, if the session is lost, some <select> would not fill properly since authentication is done in every ajax request too. It seems we're on the right track though!

Comment: @ÉrikRykDesjardins well as i said when the session is lost while the user fills out the form just show a modal login form and there you are the sesion is valid again...

Answer (score 0):

What makes a session expire in your CRM? Expiring after X time passes since last [user] action is pretty conventional and will allow you to use ajax to keep the session alive. Let's say a session is good for 5 minutes <strike>as part of security requirements for super-secret NSA banking CRM with kittens and youtube videos</strike>. A good scenario of how a session can be extended would be this:

1. a page is opened, validating the session for another 5 minutes
2. a timeout is set with JS to make an ajax request every 4 minutes
3. [4 minutes later] the request is made, returning a very light-weight response.
4. if the response says everything is ok and the session is still valid, schedule another "ping" and carry on as usual. If the response comes back with an error (session invalidated on the server because of logging in from a different PC etc.), gracefully handle it. Allow the users to retain what they were working, don't just kick them out to a log in screen with an error
5. User navigates away from the page (clicks a link, submits a form), repeat from the beginning. If the user navigates to an external site or closes the browser, his session will self-destruct in no more than 5 minutes :)

Obviously you can piggy-back any additional information onto the ajax call in step 3 - e.g. notifying the user of new items assigned to them in CRM?

Google is your friend, [one of the first results](http://www.div-tags.com/javascript/keep-session-alive-ajax-ping/) gives a not bad overview of the approach basics.